how to make multiple condition filtering card
enter image description here
I'm making a website, but I have problem in js.
What i make is card filtering. There are checkboxes, each checkbox have an id: a, b, c, d. also the card have id too but card have multiple id, and random.
If checkbox "a" checked then card with an id of "a" is displayed, and b checkbox checked also b card is displayed.
And here is my problem if i unchecked checkbox "b", I want remain "a" cards but all card is gone.
And next problem is if i checked the "reset" checkbox, "a" cards are remain.
// 각 체크박스의 상태를 추적하기 위한 객체
const checkboxStates = {};

seriesCheck.forEach((checkbox) => {
  checkboxStates[checkbox.id] = false;

  checkbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    checkboxStates[checkbox.id] = checkbox.checked;

    cardSeries.forEach((card) => {
      const seriesCheckList = card.closest('li');
      let shouldBeVisible = false;
      seriesCheck.forEach((checkbox) => {
        if (
          checkboxStates[checkbox.id] &&
          card.textContent.includes(checkbox.id)
        ) {
          shouldBeVisible = true;
        }
      });

      seriesCheckList.style.display = shouldBeVisible ? 'block' : 'none';
    });
  });
});

I think includes is the problem then how can I checked card filter?

Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

I think the problem you are facing is because when a checkbox flips to the checked state is easy to determine which cards should be added as visible but is not as straightforward to determine which should be hidden when the state flips to unchecked.
Plus in your change event listener you are targeting checkbox.checked; instead of relying on the event.target.
By the way here's another working strategy split in 2 parts.
The part adding the change event listener to all the checkboxes found: when the event will fire, the id of the clicked checkbox will be added or removed from the list of checked ids based on its true/value.
The part refreshing the visibility of all the cards based on the checkedIds list and that gets called at the end of the change event listener every time it occurs. It will always hide all the card every time upfront, before evaluating if each one should be shown or not.


function refreshCards(){
  //for each card
  for(let card of document.querySelectorAll('.card')){
    //hide the card
    card.style.display = 'none';
    //for each checked id
    for(let id of checkedIds){
      //if the current card contains the current id
      if (card.textContent.includes(id)){
        //show the card
        card.style.display = 'inline-block';
        //and exit the loop and skip to the next card
        break;
      }
    }    
  }  
}

let checkedIds = [];

//for all the checkboxes on the page
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .forEach( cb => {
    //adds a change event listener that,
    cb.addEventListener('change', event => {      
      //if the checkbox is checked
      if(event.target.checked){
        //will add the clicked checkbox id to the selectedIds array
        checkedIds.push(event.target.id);
      }
      //otherwise
      else{
        //will remove the clicked checbkox id from the selectedIds array
        checkedIds = checkedIds.filter(id => id !== event.target.id);
      }
      refreshCards();
    })
  });
.container{
  display: flex;
}

.card{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: solid 1px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

li{
  display: block;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
  
}
<div class="container">
  <label for="a">a</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="a">

  <label for="b">b</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="b">

  <label for="c">c</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c">

  <label for="d">d</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="d">
</div>

<hr>

<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="card">a b c</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="card">b c</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="card">d</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="card">a d</div>
  </li>
</ul>



